# Не работает переменная в кавычках, внутри цикла bat файла?

Tags: bat

Есть имя файла, например 21-Wi.txt.
Необходимо в именах файлов выполнить деление строки по символу "-".
Если использовать такой код, то все работает, выводит 21.

```
set "x=21-Wi"
set "x1=%x:-=" & set "x2=%"
echo !x1!
```

Но если поместить это в цикл для обхода файлов в каталоге, то выводит "-=".

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR %%I IN ("*.txt") DO (
    SET fne=%%~nxI
    SET fn=%%~nI
    
    set "x1=%fn:-=" & set "x2=%"
    
    echo !x1!
)

Pause
```

Comment: IN ("*.txt") может я ошибаюсь но там кавычки лишние ( *.doc *.txt *.me)

Comment: @Интик кавычки убрал, но ничего не изменилось. Странное поведение именно внутри цикла.

Answer (score 0):

Этот батник должен вывести только числа:

```
@echo off

FOR %%a IN ("*.txt") DO for /f "usebackq tokens=1 delims=-" %%b in ('%%~na') do echo.%%b

Pause
```

Comment: Всего должно быть три строки: